Why is navigator.onLine camelcased?
After briefly pulling my hair over navigator.online resolving to undefined in Chrome, I then found out from the spec that the correct variable is navigator.onLine. Relevant MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine
What is the reason this term is camelcased here? I have never seen it used like this anywhere, and online to my knowledge is a perfectly valid word by itself.

Maybe its definition is very old? Not aligned with today's expectations?

This article has a graph that shows two words was more common than one word until 1980. https://writingexplained.org/online-or-on-line

According to a few old discussions I've found, it was first added in IE 4.0, to indicate whether the user had selected "Work Offline" in the menu. See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc304129(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN Getting the original history may need some deep diving!
